# How to avoid Page_Load() on button click?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms, asp.net-4.0

I have two buttons, preview and Save. With help of preview button user can view the data based on the format and then can save.

But when preview is clicked, one textbox attached to ajaxcontrol (Calender) becomes empty and user have to fill the date before saving. How to handle this? On preview click i get the details to show the data in layout.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" ReadOnly="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <div style="float: right;">
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgcalender1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/calendar.png"
                            ImageAlign="Bottom" />
                        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="ajCal" TargetControlID="txtpublishDate" PopupButtonID="imgcalender1"
                            runat="server">
                        </asp:CalendarExtender>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2"  ValidationGroup="group1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDate"
                            ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="true" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </div>

<asp:Button ID="btnPreview" runat="server" Text="Preview" OnClick="btnPreview_Click" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" runat="server" ValidationGroup="group1" Text="Save" OnClick="btnsubmit_Click" />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what I am understanding the preview button is causing a postback and you do not want that, try this on your preview button:

```
<asp:button runat="server".... OnClientClick="return false;" />
```

similarly this also works:

```
YourButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", return false");
```

Edit:

it seems the answer to the user's question was simple change in the HTML mark up of the preview button

```
CausesValidation="False"
```

Comment: This doesn't work.I edited my question. Actually on click on preview button i go on server side to get the details of all the control and then show it different layout.

Comment: try CausesValidation="False", attribute on your preview button and let me know if that works

Answer (score 16):

Use Page.IsPostback() in your aspx code (server-side).  Like this:

```
private void Page_Load()
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // the code that only needs to run once goes here
    }
}
```

This code will only run the *first* time the page is loaded and avoids stepping on user-entered changes to the form.

Answer (score 3):

you can put your code in

```
Page_Init()
{
   //put your code here
}
```

instead of

```
Page_Load()
{
   //code
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and the solution above of "CausesValidation="False"" and even adding "UseSubmitBehavior="False"" DID NOT work - it still called "Page_Load" method.

What worked for me was adding the following line up front in Page_Load method.

```
if (IsPostBack) return;
```

I am mentioning this if it helps someone (I meant to comment above but StackOverflow did not allow me to comment because I am a new user - hence a new reply).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to the buttons properties in the aspx page.

```
OnClientClick="return false;"
```

Answer (score 0):

For my the @tgolisch answer worked better, maybe it's because i'm still a rookie.

I was trying to load a simple captcha in my WebForm and end up using a Reference Type in the Page_Load event and in a Button Click event (for a code snippet).

In the end i only have to edit some things and it's done:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            var captchaText = generateCaptchaCode(5);
            lblCaptcha.Text = captchaText;
        }
    }

    protected void btnCheckCaptcha_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtCaptchaCode.Text == lblCaptcha.Text)
            lblMessage.Text = "Right input characters";
        else
            lblMessage.Text = "Error wrong characters";
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
form1.Action = Request.RawUrl;
```

Write this code on page load then page is not post back on button click