# Asp.net button avoid pageload onclick

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one asp button I want avoid pageload on button click
Plz someone help

Even JavaScript method will be ok for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid Page\_Load() on button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690963/how-to-avoid-page-load-on-button-click)

Comment: I tried this but it's same as it was

Comment: In the markup can you use OnClientClick event instead of OnClick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The framework fundamentally does not work that way.  If you stay true to the framework, you can wrap your button in an update panel.  That will remove the visible postback, but that will still fire the postback and perform the page load and click event.

In essence the update panel will dump your entire page into memory, then reload only the differences, simulating an ajax request.

The link submitted only allows the button to perform a JavaScript function, which would still need to Ajax to the backend.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upSample" runat="server" ...>
      <ContentTemplate>   
           <asp:Button id="btnSample" runat="server" ... />                              
      </ContentTemplate>                                  
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Otherwise you should not use a server side event at all, simply do traditional html `<input type="button" click="btnSample_Click()" />` that is actually doing Ajax directly to the server side.

Comment: Will this <input type="button" click ="btnSample_click()"/> call my cs file onclick function

Comment: That would require a post, so the type would need to be submit or you would need to write Ajax calling a generic handler file to execute your event.